# SharePoint Pnp PowerShell date query

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am working with SharePoint Online and want to build a query with PnP PowerShell  that checks if any dates in the date field `Aviseringsdatum` is equal to todays date. But my code still returns all items (currently 2 items in the list. One with the date today and one with the date yesterday). Any ideas?

The Code

```
 $Today = (Get-date).ToString( "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ" )
    $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Avtal" -Query "
        <Query>
           <Where>
              <eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='Aviseringsdatum' />
                 <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$Today</Value>
              </eq>
           </Where>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
           <FieldRef Name='Title' />
           <FieldRef Name='Aviseringsdatum' />
           <FieldRef Name='Avtalsansvarig' />
        </ViewFields>
        <QueryOptions />
        ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<View>` attribute in CAML query.

PnP PowerShell internally uses CSOM.

To query list items in CSOM, you need `<View>` attribute.

So, modify your code as below:

```
$Today = (Get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ")

$camlQuery = $("<View>
        <Query>
           <Where>
              <Eq>
                 <FieldRef Name='Aviseringsdatum' />
                 <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'>$Today</Value>
              </Eq>
           </Where>
        </Query>
        <ViewFields>
           <FieldRef Name='Title' />
           <FieldRef Name='Aviseringsdatum' />
           <FieldRef Name='Avtalsansvarig' />
        </ViewFields>
    </View>")

$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Avtal" -Query $camlQuery
```

You can also, replace the line to use the out of the box `<Today/>` element as below:

```
<Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
```

so, your full code would be like :

```
$camlQuery = $("<View>
            <Query>
               <Where>
                  <Eq>
                     <FieldRef Name='Aviseringsdatum' />
                     <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>
                  </Eq>
               </Where>
            </Query>
            <ViewFields>
               <FieldRef Name='Title' />
               <FieldRef Name='Aviseringsdatum' />
               <FieldRef Name='Avtalsansvarig' />
            </ViewFields>
        </View>")

$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Avtal" -Query $camlQuery
```

Comment: Tried your code, got this error message, cant pinpoint what is causing the error. `Get-PnPListItem : Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904
+ $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List "Avtal" -Query $camlQuery
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPListItem], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.GetListItem`

Comment: Looks like query is malformed. Are you using the correct internal column names ? This usually happens when the internal name is wrong

Comment: Checked the code for correct internal column names but no luck, but talked to my collgue and we will fetch all the items at first and do the date check in our own code. We need all the items anyway for other reasons. But Thank you for you help and effort!

Comment: Apologies, just for my sake and curiosity, can you check with edited code ? Updated the casing of the `eq` operator to `Eq`

Comment: I am on the go right now, but will do as soon as I get to my computer.

Comment: Any luck ? Caml queries are quite case sensitive in my experience

Comment: Tried it and still no luck, The query returns 0. Dubble checked the internal names

Comment: I often find it hard to get date queries to work correctly. Its probably because I need more time with CAML queries. But nevertheless, it's frustrating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163027/discussion-between-gautam-sheth-and-allramest).